# How can I access to every single weather this api include in Kotlin ,I want put these data to RecyclerView and show as a list

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-recyclerview

[image]

Do I need for loop??

How can I get this list and put it in a RecyclerView then, for example, use `weather.main` in a TextView?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I created all classes 
**class DataForcast(val city:String ,val list:ArrayList<ListF>)
class ListF(val weather: List<WeatherF>,val dt :Double,val dt_txt:String)
//class MAinForcast(val temp:Double)
class WeatherF(val id:Double,val main: String,val description:String)**
and in my recycler view I use array list<ListF>  and pass that list in main activity but when I run this program I have this Error..**Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Retrofit** library to get the data you want from the API, then put this data in a **RecyclerView adapter** to show it.
 Follow this [tutorial](https://tutorialwing.com/retrofit-library-with-recyclerview-in-kotlin-example/)

Comment: Thanks a lot,but I get the data with Retrofit but  I have this error in forecast..
**Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote?
Open a new question with your code or update this

Answer (score 0):

**Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $** 
-- This error means that the model class you created is not matching the response you are getting from the server. You can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to convert your JSON response to POJO class and then check whether the problem persists or not..